# Spring Boot Kotlin Coroutine Caching of Http Calls

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-cache, kotlin-coroutines

i am trying to use the spring-boot caching mechanism to cache a http response which i get. Currently i have an http client which makes an 
rest call for me. I want the result to be cached.

So i created a service which adds a cachable layer:

```
@Cacheable("logicalTime", sync = true)
open fun getLogicalTimeById(dsId: String, idLogicalTimes: String): LogicalTime {
    return logicalTimeResource.getById(dsId, idLogicalTimes)
}
```

logicalTimeResource is a proxy to the rest api.

The application framework looks like this:

- a sheduler which is called every second
- iterates through a List with entries
- Calls getLogicalTimeById for each entry in a Coroutine:

  `GlobalScope.launch {
  getLogicalTime(element.dsId, element.idLogicalTime
  }`

i'd expect that the cache is looked up for the dsId and idLogicalTimes, and when there is an entry for this pair of values, it is returned from the cache. Otherwise `logicalTimeResource.getById(dsId, idLogicalTimes)`

Now the problem is that `logicalTimeResource.getById(dsId, idLogicalTimes)` is called for every element in the List.
Yes i have `@EnableCaching` at my Applicaiton.kt

Edit:

I created a small gist which shows that the cache is not working:
https://gist.github.com/H3npi/799df85d4570e3cbe8b02ede24bea5a8

The main Application looks like this:

```
package com.example.cachetest

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
class CachetestApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<CachetestApplication>(*args)
}
```

I see both requests hitting my api service on localhost.

Edit v2:

Thanks to Stephane Nicoll pointing out that caching in the same class doesn't work, i updated the gist and moved all calls to a repo class. This looks like this: https://gist.github.com/H3npi/af37ea97ea3450deeca2ab8933072c94

Comment: I'd remove `sync`, you don't want to pay the cost of the synchronization just to avoid two concurrent HTTP calls on the same tuple. It's impossible to say what is going on with the details you've given. What is the cache library? Have you looked at the auto-configuration report that caching is active?

Comment: thanks for the `sync` note! Currently i am using the default cache library, no additional configuration done. The cache should be working, because i see a `] o.s.c.a.AnnotationCacheOperationSource   : Adding cacheable method 'getLogicalTimeById' with attribute: ` in my log

Comment: Sorry I can't help you with the details you've shared. Perhaps you can share a small sample on github that reproduces the problem. If the cache isn't working, it should be quite easy to replicate.

Comment: i'll set up a sample project and send you the link!

Comment: I just added a small example to the main post

Comment: You are calling the method within the same class, it doesn't go through the proxy as explained in the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-annotation-enable

Comment: Thanks for the input, totaly forgot that in my example! I just moved the spapi calls to another class, so i guess it should be working now, but it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was: My Component was not autowired. Autowiring fixed the issue.